# Remove all columns from a CellTable

Tags: gwt

I'm using a CellTable from GWT 2.1.0.M3.  There are removeColumn functions, but no removeAllColumns or anything.  Since "columns" is a private member of CellTable, not even my extension of CellTable can easily access it.

For now, I'm just storing the number of columns I add so I can remember to remove them all.  Anyone know a better way?

Comment: If you're removing all columns, why not create a new CellTable instead?

Comment: I have a reference to a CellTable that is also in use by another part of the code, so I really need to clear that instance instead of creating another.

Comment: ...or organize your code differently - don't store the reference to the CellTable in other classes - make them use a getter exposed in the class that holds the CellTable. Don't worry about performance - the GWT Compiler will inline it all and probably convert to static invokes :)

Comment: The CellTable is instantiated inside a UiBinder widget by some deferred magic of GWT.  I don't have access to GWT's reference of the CellTable... I don't think!  Maybe there's a way to get in there.

Comment: Yes, you can :) Add the `ui:field='someNameHere'` property to the CellTable tag in UiBinder and add a `@UiField CellTable someNameHere;` declaration in your class. `someNameHere` will then reference to the `CellTable` created by UiBinder magic.

Comment: someNameHere will reference the same CellTable as GWT, but someNameHere is not the same reference that GWT uses.  To see what I mean, make a new UiBinder widget with a button with ui:field="theButton" and text "Hello."  Then, in your code, set theButton = new Button("Goodbye.").  The Hello button will still be visible, because GWT is not using the same reference you are.  There's a "Goodbye." button floating around somewhere, but you haven't added it to any framework and UiBinder has not done so automatically - UiBinder is still using the old object and does not give you access to it.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this way

1. Take count of columns of table

`int count = this.getView().getTbcell().getColumnCount();`

1. Loop through and remove first column

   `for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
       this.getView().getTbcell().removeColumn(0);
   }`

Thats it we are done :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
while (cellTable.getColumnCount() > 0) {
    cellTable.removeColumn(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what your looking for but it works for me:

```
getCellTable().setVisibleRange(0, 0);
listViewAdapter.updateRowData(0, result);
getCellTable().setVisibleRange(0, 10);
```

Comment: Does this remove columns as well?  My columns change when the row data changes, so I need to remove them all and add new ones.

Comment: I have not encountered that situation; probably not.  Is your current solution of removing the columns one by one currently working?

Comment: I was in the same situation when using the DropDownListBox (from the incubator)...There is no clear() or removeAll() method, so when using it with UiBinder a similar problem arouse.  I ended up creating a flowPanel using UiBinder and adding the DropDownListBox into it using Java code.  Then i could clear the flowPanel and add a new DropDownListBox when i needed to clear the items.  This would work in your case also, but it seems the solution you have is better.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather keep the widget directly in the UiBinder xml code so that it can be styled easily.  And yes, removing the columns one-by-one is currently working, but it has me scared that some API change will come along and break it.  Thanks for the comments!