# GWT DataGrid setEmptyTableWidget, no results, and no horizontal scollbars when more columns than current window will display

Tags: gwt, datagrid, multiple-columns

[image: Sample Layout]

I'm using a `DataGrid` in one of my layouts. I have successfully specified some static text to display when there are no results using `setEmptyTableWidget(Widget)`.  Usually, I pass something like `new HTML("No results")`.

But... when I have more columns than I can fit within the view port (i.e., current display width of browser window), I do not see all column headers, nor can I scroll to (the right to) view them.

I have a layout that supports scrolling when there IS data! But the horizontal scrollbar DOES NOT appear when there is no data.  I cannot see my way out of this problem.

Any hints or suggestions are welcomed.

Here's my layout...  (you will see where I call `setEmptyTableWidget` in  `PagingDataTableDatGrid#initGrid(DataGridConfiguration)`'s method implementation below).

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
         xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
         xmlns:com="urn:import:org.spp.im.mui.gwt.client.module.common.widget.grid">

<ui:with field="res" type="org.spp.im.mui.gwt.client.resources.UiResources" />
<ui:with field="msg" type="org.spp.im.mui.gwt.shared.i18n.UiMessages" />

<!-- Layout -->
<gwt:DockLayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%" styleName="{res.style.container}" unit="PX">
    <gwt:north size="25">
        <gwt:HorizontalPanel width="100%">
            <!-- Buttons -->
            <gwt:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_RIGHT">
                <com:GridButtonBar ui:field="bar" />
            </gwt:cell>
        </gwt:HorizontalPanel>
    </gwt:north>
    <gwt:center>
        <!-- Grid -->
        <com:ReadOnlyGrid ui:field="grid" width="100%" />
    </gwt:center>
    <gwt:south size="25">
        <gwt:HorizontalPanel width="100%">
            <!-- Pagination controls -->
            <gwt:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_LEFT">
                    <com:CustomPager ui:field="pager" width="225px" />
            </gwt:cell>
        </gwt:HorizontalPanel>
    </gwt:south>
</gwt:DockLayoutPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

`ReadOnlyGrid` is a custom implementation...

```
public class ReadOnlyGrid extends PagingDataTableDataGrid<DataRow> {

private Set<Column<DataRow, ?>> columns = new HashSet<Column<DataRow, ?>>();

// preferred constructor in most cases
public ReadOnlyGrid() {
    super();
}

public ReadOnlyGrid(final DataGridConfiguration config) {
    super(config);
}

@Override
protected Set<Column<DataRow, ?>> allColumns() {
    return columns;
}

@Override
// first column always has default ascending sort order
public void initTableColumns(final DataGrid<DataRow> dataGrid, final DataTable table,
        final ListHandler<DataRow> sortHandler) {
    Column<DataRow, String> column;

    final int totalColumns = table.getColumnCount();
    String columnName = null;
    ColumnHints columnHints = null;
    for (int col = 0; col < totalColumns; col++) {
        final int c = col;
        columnName = table.getColumnName(c);
        columnHints = table.getColumnHints(columnName);
        if (columnHints.isVisible()) {
            column = new Column<DataRow, String>(new DataTableCell()) {

                @Override
                public String getValue(final DataRow row) {
                    String result = "";
                    if (row != null) {
                        result = row.get(c);
                    }
                    return result;
                }

            };
            column.setSortable(true);
            sortHandler.setComparator(column, new Comparator<DataRow>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(final DataRow r1, final DataRow r2) {
                    final String one = r1.get(c);
                    final String two = r2.get(c);

                    if (one == null ^ two == null) {
                        return one == null ? -1 : 1;
                    }

                    if (one == null && two == null) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    return one.compareToIgnoreCase(two);
                }
            });
            final String header = columnHints.getColumnHeader() == null ? columnName : columnHints.getColumnHeader();
            // create the column header
            // header should have the same alignment as the column data
            dataGrid.addColumn(column, createHeader(header, columnHints.getColumnAlignment()));
            // keep track of columns added
            allColumns().add(column);

            // Set the column width
            dataGrid.setColumnWidth(column, columnHints.getColumnWidth(), Unit.PX);

            // Set the column alignment
            if (columnHints.getColumnAlignment() != null) {
                column.setHorizontalAlignment(columnHints.getColumnAlignment());
            }
            else {
                column.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);//default
            }

            if (c == 0) {
                dataGrid.getColumnSortList().push(column);
            }
        }

    }

}

@Override
protected void initTableRows(final DataTable table) {
    setDataList(table.allRows());
}

private SafeHtml createHeader(final String columnHeaderHtml, HasHorizontalAlignment.HorizontalAlignmentConstant columnHeaderAlignment) {
    columnHeaderAlignment = columnHeaderAlignment == null ? HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT : columnHeaderAlignment;
    final String ch = replaceCrWithBr(columnHeaderHtml);
    final SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div align=\"" + columnHeaderAlignment.getTextAlignString() + "\">")
    .appendHtmlConstant(ch).appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
    final SafeHtml header = sb.toSafeHtml();
    return header;
}

private String replaceCrWithBr(final String value) {
    String result = value;
    if (value.contains(App.INSTANCE.carriage_return())) {
        result = value.replace(App.INSTANCE.carriage_return(), App.INSTANCE.separator());
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

And `PagingDataTableDataGrid`...

```
public abstract class PagingDataTableDataGrid<T extends DataRow> extends Composite {

private DataGrid<T> dataGrid;
private ListDataProvider<T> dataProvider;
private ResizeLayoutPanel wrapper;

// default, use in UiBinder template when you just want to @UiField inject a subclass
public PagingDataTableDataGrid() {
    this(new DefaultDataGridConfiguration());
}

// alternate, use in UiBinder template when you want to create an instance
// yourself, user to inject w/ @UiField(provided=true)
public PagingDataTableDataGrid(final DataGridConfiguration config) {
    wrapper = new ResizeLayoutPanel();
    wrapper.setWidth("100%");
    wrapper.setStyleName(UiResources.INSTANCE.style().gridWrapper());
    initWidget(wrapper);
    initGrid(config);
}

private void initGrid(final DataGridConfiguration config) {
    dataGrid = new DataGrid<T>(config.getPageSize(), config.getResources());
    final HTML noResults = new HTML(UiMessages.INSTANCE.no_results());
    dataGrid.setEmptyTableWidget(noResults);
    wrapper.clear();
    wrapper.add(dataGrid);
}

public void setInput(final DataTable table) {
    resetTableColumns();
    dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<T>();
    dataProvider.setList(new ArrayList<T>());
    final ListHandler<T> sortHandler = new ListHandler<T>(dataProvider.getList());
    dataGrid.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
    initTableColumns(dataGrid, table, sortHandler);
    initTableRows(table);
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(dataGrid);

    // trigger sort client-side
    ColumnSortEvent.fire(dataGrid, dataGrid.getColumnSortList());

    GridUtil.setStyles(this.dataGrid);
}

protected abstract Set<Column<T, ?>> allColumns();

// see
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772480/remove-all-columns-from-a-celltable
// concrete classes are forced to maintain a handle on all columns added
private void resetTableColumns() {
    for (final Column<T, ?> column : allColumns()) {
        dataGrid.removeColumn(column);
    }
    allColumns().clear();
}

/**
 * Add columns to this grid
 * 
 * @param dataGrid
 *            a GWT DataGrid implementation
 * @param table
 *            the model data
 * @param sortHandler
 *            a GWT ListHandler implementation
 */
protected abstract void initTableColumns(DataGrid<T> dataGrid, DataTable table, ListHandler<T> sortHandler);

/**
 * Add rows to this grid
 * @param table the model data
 */
protected abstract void initTableRows(DataTable table);

protected void setDataList(final List<T> dataList) {
    final List<T> list = dataProvider.getList();
    list.addAll(dataList);
    dataProvider.refresh();
}

public DataGrid<T> getDataGrid() {
    return dataGrid;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as a "hack" I managed to get the behavior I wanted by using an insanely large pixel value for the width of the `Widget`.

E.g.,

```
Label noResults = new Label("No results");
noResults.setWidth("20000px");
```

This has the effect of pushing the text of the label all the way to the left, instead of it being centered underneath the column headers. But I can live w/ that, b/c the column headers are then scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It is as designed by the gwt. Why should a scroll appear if there is no data. Even I had similar doubt when working with datagrid but seriously it doesn't make sense to provide scroll when there is no data.

Comment: What if the user wants to know what all the column headers were?  Consider an uninformed user trying to understand the results.  What would he or she expect to see versus actually seeing. There's no way I can see to get scrollbars to appear other than adding a fake row of data.  Underneath the covers GWT `DataGrid` uses a `FlexTable` to hold the `emptyTableWidget` and adds whatever `Widget` to the `0,0` coordinate of that table.  Is there some other `Widget` variant I could add to make scrollbars appear?